Rank-preserving linear transformations over rings
Let $f:\operatorname{Mat}_{m \times n}(\mathbb{F}_q) \to \operatorname{Mat}_{m \times n}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ be an invertible, rank-preserving linear map. Then we have the characterisation that $f(A)=PAQ \ (1)$, for suitable invertible matrices $P, Q$ (up to transposition of $A$ when $m=n$).
I am trying to understand the situation when we replace the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ by a finite chain ring $R$, in particular characterise invertible $R$-module homomorphisms between matrices that preserve the length of the row space of a matrix.
I have seen proofs of $(1)$ (1, 2), but the arguments used cannot be translated to the $R$-module situation. It is clear that maps of the form $(1)$ also work over $R$, but I was wondering whether they are the only ones. Thinking on the level of the generator matrices $E_{ij}$ (whose entries are $1$ in the $i,j$-th position and $0$ everywhere else), I believe that maps of the form $(1)$ are indeed the only ones, but am I missing something? Maybe finding $R$-module homomorphisms that take free cyclic modules to free cyclic modules is key, but I cannot think of such maps, other than multiplication by a unit.
Edit: A finite chain ring is a finite local principal ideal ring, and its ideals form a chain under inclusion, the prototypical example being $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$. Here is a complete characterisation.
Edit no.$2$: Obviously, any new type of map in the case of rings has to become of the form $(1)$ when $R$ is a field.

Please include (or link to) a definition of a "finite chain ring"

@BenGrossmann Edited to add definition.

Here is something for square matrices. Bernard R. McDonald, "$R$-linear endomorphisms of $(R)_n$ preserving invariants" (Memoirs AMS 287), p. 40, Corollary (F.5):

Let $R$ be a local [commutative] ring and $T$: $(R)_n \to (R)_n$ a linear mapping which carries rank one matrices to rank one matrices. Then, there exist invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that either $T(A) = P A Q^{-1}$ for all $A$ in $(R)_n$ or $T(A) = P A^t Q^{-1}$ for all $A$ in $(R)_n$.

A matrix over a commutative ring is said to be of rank one (as defined in section (E), p. 32), if the $R$-module generated by the columns of $A$ is a "rank one" projective module, which is defined as "the localized module $P_q$ is free of $R_q$-dimension one for each prime ideal $q$ in $R$" (i.e., apparently, just a free module of rank $1$ in this situation).
In the beginning of section (F), he says

The method of proof is a direct lifting of the theory from the known results over the field $k$.

